# Different $PATH between slave and Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-cli

In the machine where Jenkins is installed I have the `$PATH` variable with the value `X`. I start Jenkins, from the same machine, with the command:

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

but when I see the info from `http://<url>/systemInfo` the `$PATH` has a different value from the one I see in the machine. I was wondering the reason why this happens and if there is a solution for this problem that does not require any plugin to install (I saw that a plugin like EnvInject could be a solution).